# Wix re-register DLL on repair action

Tags: dll, wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I have an MSI that includes a DLL file that is registered using the following code:

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Id="XYZ.dll" Guid="<GUID>">
      <File Id="XYZ.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="XYZ.dll" SelfRegCost="1" />
    </Component>
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Now after installation I manually register a different version of the file (using regsvr32). I rerun the MSI installation and do a repair. The manual DLL isn't overwritten by MSI DLL in the repair action. Is there a work around so I can get the MSI DLL when I do the repair action.

Comment: MSI is trying to avoid DLL hell. A higher version DLL wins.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a repair is to restore the state of the installed product to the specification in the MSI file. So, what exactly does "different version" mean? For example, if your Dll was file version 2.0 and you replaced it with a 1.0 version then a repair will restore the 2.0 version.  However if you replace a 2.0 file version with a 3.0 file version then a repair will not overwrite the higher version with a lower version. That's because the default REINSTALLMODE for a repair is (IIRC) pocmus, which means replace if missing, equal or older version.

So this may help, but if not you should say something about your file versions because replacement is based on them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The DLL in the MSI is a higher version. This gets replaced by a lower version DLL using regsvr32 (the original file is still present in the install directory). Repair action should re-register the DLL from the MSI, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying the COM registration is being written by using self-registration on either of two different files. In your scenario (with made up numbers and names), the MSI is installed, registering version 2 of ComClassA_v2.dll. Then someone copies in ComClassA_v1.dll with version 1 and registers it. You now expect a product repair to re-register ComClassAv2.dll.

It won't because the file is the keypath. The file is versioned. So, the version of existing file is compared to the version in the MSI. They match, so the component is considered as not needing repair.

I would <strike>try to</strike> avoid this method of implementing the "strategy design pattern." But, the smallest change to your procedure would be to simply delete ComClassA_v2.dll before the repair.